# Mark accumulated values on a QlikView column if condition is fulfilled

Tags: qlikview

I have a table in Qlikview with 2 columns:

```
A B   
a 10 
b 45 
c 30 
d 15
```

Based on this table, I have a formula with full acumulation defined as:
SUM(a)/SUM(TOTAL a)

As a result,

```
A B   D             
b 45 45/100=0.45 
c 30 75/100=0.75
d 15 90/100=0.90
a 10 100/100=1
```

**My question is. how do I mark in colour the values in column A that have on column D <=0.8)?**
*The challenge is that D is defined with full accumulation, but if I reference D in a formula, it doesn't consider the full accumulation!*

I tried with defining a formula E=if(D>0.8,'Y','N') but this formula doesn't take the visible (accumulated) value for D unfortunately, instead it takes the D with no accumulation. If this worked, I would have tried to hide (not disable) E and reference it from the dimensions column of the table , Text colour option. Any ideas please?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get an expression column's value from within a dimension or it's properties, because the expression columns rely on the dimensions provided. It would create an endless loop. Your options are:

- Apply your background colour to the expression columns, not the dimensions. This would actually make more sense as the accumulated values would have the colour, not the dimension.
- When loading this specific table, have QlikView create a new column that contains the accumulated values of B. This would mean, however, that the order of your chart-table would need to be fixed for the accumulations to make any sense.
- Use aggregation to create a temporary table and accumulate the values using RangeSum(). Note this will only accumulate properly if the table is ordered in Ascending order of Column A

  ```
  =IF(Aggr(RangeSum(Above(Sum(B),0,10)),A)/100>0.8,
      rgb(0,0,0),
      rgb(255,0,0)
  )
  ```